# Flask/AngluarJS Deploying to Heroku

Tags: python, angularjs, heroku, flask

I've got a newbee question. I want to deploy my Flask app (simple REST) to heroku. I want to serve the backend with **Flask** but I would also like to serve a front-end via **AngularJS**. Do I need to create two separate heroku apps ? one for front-end second for backend? OR Maybe I can pull it of inside one heroku app/process ? I am looking forward to all responses, cheers !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to create two separate Heroku apps. Create a single Heroku app, where your Flask backend serves the front-end experience to the user.

For example:

Say your Flask app serves some `index.html` to the user:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

Make sure you add AngularJs to the `index.html` file you are serving the user. Add the following line to your `index.html`. Remember to update this based on whatever version of AngularJS you are using. In this example, I am using version `1.4.9`.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.min.js"></script>
```

I suggest that you read up on the [client-server model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client%E2%80%93server_model) as that will help you understand the role of the client and server, and how they interact.

Comment: hi,@Muntaser Ahmed thanks for your reply ! much appreciated but I've got another question if I serve my index.html over flask can I use angular routing later ?

Comment: Glad I can help! You can use Flask to handle any RESTful API calls and let AngularJS handle the static templates using angular routing. That is one way of going about it.

Comment: Check out flask-app-generator, you may find it useful: https://github.com/shea256/flask-app-generator